# Informix - Best Practice - SQL Error [42000]: A syntax error has occurred

Tags: sql, informix

I often try to execute an insert statement with the database informix. However, I often get the following error:

`SQL Error [42000]: A syntax error has occurred.`

The insert statement could be:

```
INSERT INTO 
     example_table
             (key, value, type, description, is_active, created_at, created_by)
     VALUES
             ('output', 'C:\temp', 'string', 'location for the output', true, current, 'admin');
```

I don't see any error here, but informix shows me the above mentioned error:

`SQL Error [42000]: A syntax error has occurred.`

For completeness, here are the data types for the columns from the above example:

| Column | Column type |
| --- | --- |
| id | serial |
| key | char(50) |
| value | char(256) |
| type | char(10) |
| description | char(512) |
| created_at | datetime year to second |
| created_by | char(20) |

Is there a best practice to find such a syntax error in informix?

Comment: I think you need `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` instead of `current`

Answer (score 1):

The list of data types you have provided does not include the column is_active and this is related to the syntax error. When run from an interactive session of `dbaccess` the location of the error is indicated:

```
INSERT INTO
     example_table
             (key, value, type, description, is_active, created_at, created_by)
     VALUES
             ('output', 'C:\temp', 'string', 'location for the output', true, current, 'admin');
#                                                                       ^
#  201: A syntax error has occurred.
#
```

After updating the table DDL to include the is_active column with type boolean the statement will still fail because Informix does not recognize "true" as a boolean value. Replacing it with of 't'::boolean or just 't' will work.

Comment: Thank you @Simon Riddle. Is there a SQL client that displays the error message as detailed as dbaccess? I have used DBeaver as sql client.

Comment: Part of the error message returned from the Informix server to the client includes the offset into the statement where the error was detected. This is what dbaccess uses to show the error position.
I'm not familiar with DBeaver so I don't know whether it, or any other SQL clients, will make use of that error offset information.

Comment: This is a limitation of the Informix JDBC driver to not include the offset in the SQLException for DBeaver to display. The way Informix does the offset for a syntax error is not standard JDBC and so won't show up in these clients like DBeaver.